# How to use the full request URL in AWS Lambda to execute logic only on certain pages

Tags: node.js, security, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I have a website running on www.mywebsite.com. The files are hosted in an S3 bucket in combination with cloudFront. Recently, I have added a new part to the site, which is supposed to be only for private access, so I wanted to put some form of protection on there. The rest of the site, however, should remain public. My goal is for the site to be accessible for everyone, but as soon as someone gets to the new part, they should not see any source files, and be prompted for a username/password combination.

The URL of the new part would be for example www.mywebsite.com/private/index.html ,...

I found that an AWS Lambda function (with node.js) is good for this, and it kind of works. I have managed to authenticate everything in the entire website, but I can't figure out how to get it to work on only the pages that contain for example '/private/*' in the full URL name. The lambda function I wrote looks like this:

```
'use strict';

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {


// Get request and request headers
const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
const headers = request.headers;

  if (!request.uri.toLowerCase().indexOf("/private/") > -1) {
      // Continue request processing if authentication passed
     callback(null, request);
     return;
  }

// Configure authentication
const authUser = 'USER';
const authPass = 'PASS';

// Construct the Basic Auth string
const authString = 'Basic ' + new Buffer(authUser + ':' + authPass).toString('base64');

// Require Basic authentication
if (typeof headers.authorization == 'undefined' || headers.authorization[0].value != authString) {
    const body = 'Unauthorized';
    const response = {
        status: '401',
        statusDescription: 'Unauthorized',
        body: body,
        headers: {
            'www-authenticate': [{key: 'WWW-Authenticate', value:'Basic'}]
        },
    };
    callback(null, response);
}

// Continue request processing if authentication passed
callback(null, request);
};
```

The part that doesn't work is the following part:

```
     if (!request.uri.toLowerCase().indexOf("/private/") > -1) {
      // Continue request processing if authentication passed
     callback(null, request);
     return;
  }
```

My guess is that the request.uri does not contain what I expected it to contain, but I can't seem to figure out what does contain what I need.

Comment: It seems you're trying to protected some parts of your website now, and you're starting on this right now, I'm right?
If so, I suggest you give a try on firebase authentication with custom authorizer on api gateway (on aws side). Working with firebase is very simple and very well documented and you'll easily protect your frontend side with firebase api and on sever-side you'll create a custom authorizer lambda function to manage the custom authentication jwt token sent via Authorization Header with firebase sdk.
Even if it's not your case, but it's a new feature, think about it!

Comment: Well, I am indeed starting with this now, but the application is very simple, and I basically only want to protect 2 pages. I was trying to go for the simplest solution possible, and I would think it is easier to continue on the current path? unless ofcourse, it is not possible to get the full URL through lambda node.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My guess is that the request.uri does not contain what I expected it to contain, but I can't seem to figure out what does contain what I need.

If you're using a Lambda@Edge function (appears you are). Then you can view the Request Event structure here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-event-structure.html#lambda-event-structure-request

You can see the actual value of the request URI field by using `console.log` and checking the respective logs in Cloudwatch.

The problem might be this line:

```js
if (!request.uri.toLowerCase().indexOf("/private/") > -1) {
```

If you're strictly looking to check if a JavaScript string contains another string in it, you probably want to do this instead:

```js
if (!request.uri.toLowerCase().indexOf("/private/") !== -1) {
```

Or better yet, using more modern JS:

```js
if (!request.uri.toLowerCase().includes("/private/")) {
```

Comment: Well, that actually did it. I have used the more modern JS, '.includes()'. I had somehow debugged wrong, and thought that the > -1 was not a problem. And since I had issues properly executing and testing my code, I couldn't seem to figure out the answer. Thanks!